# All dynamically generated components are changing to the same value in VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

we are building a chat application in Vuejs, now every chat message is component in our application, now whenever we are changing the value of one chat message, the value of all chat messages changes

**What is happening**

[image]

**source code**

**App Component**

```
const App = new Vue({
      el: '#myApp',
      data: {
        children: [
          MyCmp
        ],
        m1: '',
        m2: '',
        m3: 'Hello world',
        m4: 'How are you'
      },
      methods: {
        sendMessage (event) {
          if(event.key == "Enter") {
            this.m2= this.m3;
            this.children.push(MyCmp);
          }
        },
      }
    });
```

**component code**

```
let MyCmp = {
      props: ['myMessage'],
      template: `
      <li class="self">
          <div class="avatar"><img src="" draggable="false"/></div>
          <div class="msg">
            <p>{{ myMessage }}</p>
          </div>
      </li>
      `
    };
```

** view where components are generating **

```
<ol class="chat">
        <template v-for="(child, index) in children">
          <component :is="child" :key="child.name" v-bind="{myMessage: m3}"></component>
        </template>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are creating new components by pushing them into the children array, they are still getting bound to the same data via the line `v-bind="{myMessage: m3}"`. Whenever you change `m3`, it will be passed down to all the child components and they will all render the same message.

This is an odd way of creating custom components since you could easily do so using the templating syntax or render function provided by Vue.

### Solution 1 - Recommended

Change your approach - push message strings instead of card component definitions into `children` and use `MyCmp` inside `v-for` to render the message cards.

So the new template could be refactored as :-

```
<ol class="chat">
    <template v-for="(message, index) in children">
        <my-cmp :key="index" :my-message="message"></my-cmp>
    </template>
</ol>
```

And inside App component, you can replace `this.children.push(MyCmp)` with `this.children.push(messageVariable);` where `messageVariable` contains the message that you receive from the input box.

Why is the recommended? This is a standard approach where component lists are rendered based on an array of data. It will be easier to scale and maintain.

### Solution 2

You can use the [v-once](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once) directive to bind the message one-time as static text. The binding won't be updated even if `m3` changes on the parent.

Then `MyCmp` template will become :-

```
<li class="self">
    <div class="avatar"><img src="" draggable="false"/></div>
        <div class="msg">
        <p v-once>{{ myMessage }}</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You bind `myMessage` of all your components instances with one variable `m3`. So, when `m3` is changed `myMessage` in all instances changes respectively. Use another variable (e.g. `msg`) for rendering the message and then use `myMessage` property only for the initialisation of `msg`, like this:

```js
let MyCmp = {
  props: ['myMessage'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      msg: this.myMessage
    }
  },
  template: `
    <li class="self">
      <div class="avatar"><img src="" draggable="false"/></div>
        <div class="msg">
          <p>{{ msg }}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
   `
};
```